# Как запросом вывести все записи у которых одна колонка не уникальна?

Tags: sql

У меня есть таблица `Empl`, в которой есть колонка`LastName`.

Как мне вывести записи, у которых эта колонка не уникальна (т.е. всех однофамильцев)?

Answer (score 4):

```
select * from Empl
where LastName in(
select lastname from empl group by lastname having count(*) > 1)
```

Comment: А вот этот мне даже больше нравится. Не уверен, что он быстрее, но точно читабельнее

Answer (score 3):

На большинстве СУБД доступен станадртный запрос с аналитической функцией `COUNT`:

```
with t as (
    select e.*, count(*) over(partition by LastName) as num
    from Empl e)
select * from t where num>1
```

Классика с корреляционным подзапросом в операторе `EXISTS`:

```
select e1.*
from Empl e1
where exists (
    select null 
    from Empl e2 
    where e2.LastName = e1.LastName and e2.id != e1.id)
```

[db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=6362757f017f39296fe834a250d1b895).

Comment: Последнее посещение 17 авг 2011 в 7:38 у автора данного вопроса =)

Comment: @PotroNik Разве это играет какую-либо роль? У вопроса 4к просмотров. Неужели 4к раз сюда заходили узнать, активен ли ещё автор вопроса ;)

Comment: Хм, действительно, если как во втором варианте в таблице существует id, то можно еще `join` использовать по типу `join Empl e2 on e2.LastName = e1.LastName and e2.id != e1.id`

Comment: @PotroNik Можно, только оптимизатор скорее всего выберет точно такой же план выполнения как и с exists. Остаётся выбирать по критерию - какой запрос лучше читается.

Answer (score 2):

```
select `e1`.* from `Empl` as `e1`, (select `LastName` from `Empl` group by `LastName` having count(*)>1) as `e2` where `e1`.`LastName`=`e2`.`LastName`
```

На собеседованиях любят такие давать.
upd: пардон, запятую забыл

Answer (score 1):

Тупо в лоб

```
select distinct * from empl where lastname in(  
  select t1.lastname from empl t1, empl t2  
  where t1.lastname=t2.lastname and not t1.id=t2.id
) t;
```

Answer (score 0):

Как такой вариант?

```sql
select * from Empl GROUP BY LastName HAVING COUNT(LastName) >1
```

Comment: добро пожаловать на Stack Overflow на русском! пожалуйста, оставляйте чуть более развёрнутые ответы. [постарайтесь рассказать обо всех нюансах, которые могут возникнуть при решении проблемы по вашему сценарию. изложите свои предложения. возможен и краткий ответ, но чем подробнее и понятнее он будет изложен, тем лучше](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer). дополнить ответ можно, нажав [edit]

Comment: _Как такой вариант?_, плохо. Вы не внимательно прочли вопрос и не проверили ваш запрос, [он даже не будет работать](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_5.7&fiddle=088c855cb7f72493b3bb986e12b439d7).

Comment: Вообще-то он работает, я проверял ;-)

Comment: З.Ы. Нашел опечатку, заместо * - LastName

Comment: Ваш запрос выдаст только одну фамилию людей, которые являются однофамильцами. А надо все записи однофамильцев. Прочтите ещё раз вопрос.